# XML to Json conversion using Jackson, @JsonUnwrapped producing nulls

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson

I'm using java 8, and (fasterjackson) Jackson 2.8.1.

I have an xml which I need to convert into json using Java.  The xml structure is like so:

```
<Input>
    <ns0:order>
        <ns0:lineItemList>
            <ns0:lineItem>
                <ns0:lineItemType>
                    <ns0:orderID>234</ns0:orderID>
                    <ns0:shipmentID>1</ns0:shipmentID>
                    <ns0:lineID>1</ns0:lineID>
                    <ns0:upc>123</ns0:upc>
                    <ns0:quantity>1</ns0:quantity>
                    <ns0:retailPrice>14</ns0:retailPrice>
                </ns0:lineItemType>
            </ns0:lineItem>
        </ns0:lineItemList>
    </ns0:order>
</Input>
```

I have chosen Jackson to deserialize from xml into java, and then to serialize from java to json.  The target json needs to unwrap the "lineItem" and "lineItemType" to get json similar to this:

```
{  
  "input" : {
    "order" : {  
     "lineItemList" : [ {
        "upc" : 123,
        "quantity" : 1,
        "retailPrice" : 14,
        "orderID" : 234,
        "shipmentID" : 1,
        "lineID" : 1
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

In my java model, there are 3 relevant classes in play here:  Order, LineItem and LineItemType.  In the order class, I have annotated the like so:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="lineItemList")
@JsonProperty("lineItemList")
List<LineItem> lineItems;
```

In LineItem, like so:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="lineItemType")
@JsonUnwrapped
LineItemType lineItemType;
```

and in LineItemType it just has the properties in this pattern:

```
...
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="orderID")
@JsonProperty("orderID")
String orderId;

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="lineID")
@JsonProperty("lineID")
String lineId;

...
```

As you can see, I tried to tackle this by using @JsonUnwrapped from within the LineItem class, but the end effect is that the XMLDeserializer ends up reading this annotation and producing "null" values as such:

```
{  
  "input" : {
    "order" : {  
     "lineItemList" : [ {
        "upc" : null,
        "quantity" : null,
        "retailPrice" : null,
        "orderID" : null,
        "shipmentID" : null,
        "lineID" : null
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

If I omit the @JsonUnwrapped, the values come in, but are nested like this:

```
{  
  "input" : {
    "order" : {  
     "lineItemList" : [ {
      "lineItemType" : {
        "upc" : 123,
        "quantity" : 1,
        "retailPrice" : 14,
        "orderID" : 234,
        "shipmentID" : 1,
        "lineID" : 1
       } ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how this should be annotated to get the desired result here  (unwrapped but with values)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JsonUnwrapped is being read by Jackson's XMLMapper during deserialization.  I had assumed this was not the case as it says "Json"Unwrapped.  The solution was to remove all annotations from my model and apply XML specific annotations in mixins I registered under an XmlModule (JacksonXmlModule), and Json specific annoations in mixins I registered under a JsonModule (SimpleModule).  During deserialization from xml, I use the xmlmodule, and during serialization into json I use the jsonmodule.

The fact that the XMLMapper uses the @JsonUnwrapped annotation feels like a bug to me.  I think the developer was thinking that @JsonUnwrapped applies to serialization and deserialization generically, but I would argue that the name implies that it should be restricted to Json only.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to successfully marshal from XML into the POJO to begin with? In your XML example your first order tag is self-closing which may be causing an issue.

This is how I would lay out each of the POJOs (adding in the XmlProperties as well). This should un-marshal from the POJO into JSON correctly.

Top Level (**Example.java**):

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "input"
})
public class Example {

    @JsonProperty("input")
    private Input input;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The input
     */
    @JsonProperty("input")
    public Input getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param input
     *     The input
     */
    @JsonProperty("input")
    public void setInput(Input input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

**Input.java**:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "order"
})
public class Input {

    @JsonProperty("order")
    private Order order;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The order
     */
    @JsonProperty("order")
    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param order
     *     The order
     */
    @JsonProperty("order")
    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

**Order.java**:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "lineItemList"
})
public class Order {

    @JsonProperty("lineItemList")
    private List<LineItemList> lineItemList = new ArrayList<LineItemList>();
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The lineItemList
     */
    @JsonProperty("lineItemList")
    public List<LineItemList> getLineItemList() {
        return lineItemList;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param lineItemList
     *     The lineItemList
     */
    @JsonProperty("lineItemList")
    public void setLineItemList(List<LineItemList> lineItemList) {
        this.lineItemList = lineItemList;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

**LineItemList.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "upc",
    "quantity",
    "retailPrice",
    "orderID",
    "shipmentID",
    "lineID"
})
public class LineItemList {

    @JsonProperty("upc")
    private Integer upc;
    @JsonProperty("quantity")
    private Integer quantity;
    @JsonProperty("retailPrice")
    private Integer retailPrice;
    @JsonProperty("orderID")
    private Integer orderID;
    @JsonProperty("shipmentID")
    private Integer shipmentID;
    @JsonProperty("lineID")
    private Integer lineID;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The upc
     */
    @JsonProperty("upc")
    public Integer getUpc() {
        return upc;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param upc
     *     The upc
     */
    @JsonProperty("upc")
    public void setUpc(Integer upc) {
        this.upc = upc;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The quantity
     */
    @JsonProperty("quantity")
    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param quantity
     *     The quantity
     */
    @JsonProperty("quantity")
    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The retailPrice
     */
    @JsonProperty("retailPrice")
    public Integer getRetailPrice() {
        return retailPrice;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param retailPrice
     *     The retailPrice
     */
    @JsonProperty("retailPrice")
    public void setRetailPrice(Integer retailPrice) {
        this.retailPrice = retailPrice;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The orderID
     */
    @JsonProperty("orderID")
    public Integer getOrderID() {
        return orderID;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param orderID
     *     The orderID
     */
    @JsonProperty("orderID")
    public void setOrderID(Integer orderID) {
        this.orderID = orderID;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The shipmentID
     */
    @JsonProperty("shipmentID")
    public Integer getShipmentID() {
        return shipmentID;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param shipmentID
     *     The shipmentID
     */
    @JsonProperty("shipmentID")
    public void setShipmentID(Integer shipmentID) {
        this.shipmentID = shipmentID;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The lineID
     */
    @JsonProperty("lineID")
    public Integer getLineID() {
        return lineID;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param lineID
     *     The lineID
     */
    @JsonProperty("lineID")
    public void setLineID(Integer lineID) {
        this.lineID = lineID;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

Example output JSON:

```
{
    "input": {
        "order": {
            "lineItemList": [{
                "upc": 123,
                "quantity": 1,
                "retailPrice": 14,
                "orderID": 234,
                "shipmentID": 1,
                "lineID": 1
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tried this, it didn't solve the issue.  I still get null values when using @JsonUnwrapped and the unwanted layer in my json when I don't.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Your example wanted JSON is not valid and doesn't follow specification. If you edit it to what you want it to be then I'll have a look to see if I can help you further.

This is the JSON that my code examples output (tested):

{
 "input": {
  "order": {
   "lineItemList": [{
    "upc": 123,
    "quantity": 1,
    "retailPrice": 14,
    "orderID": 234,
    "shipmentID": 1,
    "lineID": 1
   }]
  }
 }
}

Comment: The difference between your example and mine is that you started with java and converted into json and I started with xml, converted to java, then using the same model converted into json.  The problem was there.  The XMLMapper from Jackson was actually reading and using the @JsonUnwrapped during deserialization which was unexpected by me, and ultimately what was causing the error...